# How to add new var to json

Tags: javascript

I would like to add a variable every time something happens, I have some code where when someone says a certain thing, it'll do something. I would like to do something though, which the title says of course.

I would like it to save their username and any roles they recieve into a json, how would I go about just adding a variable to the json when they run the command though (I just need how to save their name and everything currently in the json without constantly recoding)

before this is marked too broad this is what I mean

```
{
"USERNAME1" : "1"
}
```

then

```
{
"USERNAME1" : "1",
"USERNAME2" : "1"
}
```

Comment: I think you mean "add property to object": JSON is a serialisation format for a JS object. To add a property parse the JSON, add the property and then serialise.

Comment: Thank you Richard.

Why did I get negative voted though? This is a genuine question.

Comment: Because you didn't follow the help centre guidance on asking questions. For a start even a little research on JSON would have shown that object properties are not variables ("var" being an abbreviation for variable).

Comment: @Anonymous — You've basically written a requirements specification, got technical terms wrong, have written no code, and provided no evidence that you've done any research into solving this yourself.

Comment: I have, before this thread I have looked all over but no one made any threads on this, now that I know jsons don't have VARIABLES I can figure that out, no reason to neg vote me cause it seems I didn't do research,

Comment: You are in the tricky position of knowing so little about JavaScript that you cannot even express the questions you have with the right vocabulary, or search for answers to them. The best approach is to start off with a JS intro or tutorial, of which there are dozens if not hundreds, go through it real slow, doing the exercises, and learning JS step-by-step. Adding a property to a JS object is something you will learn very early in any intro or tutorial. Unfortunately, Stack Overflow is not the best place to help you--it's a Q&A site, not designed to guide beginners along.

Comment: Thank you @torazaburo I shall go learn js. You're kind.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

If what you mean by JSON is a JavaScript object created either with:

```
var object = {
  "USERNAME1" : "1"
};
```

or:

```
var object = JSON.parse('{"USERNAME1" : "1"}');
```

Then to add a new property you use:

```
object.USERNAME2 = 1;
```

or:

```
object[key] = 1;
```

where `key` is a variable or expression that contains your key that you want to add.

If what you mean by JSON is a file on your file system that contains JSON inside then see these answers:

- [Insert to locale `json` File without any modules via node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43321737/insert-to-locale-json-file-without-any-modules-via-node-js/43321978#43321978)
- [Write JSON with query pseudo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40863991/write-json-with-query-pseudo/40864731#40864731)
- [Node.js: How to write input values of a formular into a JSON file when the submit button is pressed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43213085/node-js-how-to-write-input-values-of-a-formular-into-a-json-file-when-the-submi/43213296#43213296)

Comment: Thank you RSP for helping me further.

Comment: "JSON is a JavaScript object" — [No, it isn't](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/)

Comment: @Anonymous — Amazingly enough, it is possible to spot flaws in answers without investing the effort into writing a better answer (and writing a better answer would be hypocritical since I voted to put the question on hold).

Comment: @Quentin I didn't say that JSON is a JavaScript object - I said "If what you mean by JSON is a JavaScript object" in the first part of my answer and "If what you mean by JSON is a file on your file system that contains JSON inside" in the second part. I even included parsing real JSON string in my answer. I don't know why the answer was downvoted so much.